# Windows-10 CreateFile2 error (ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_IN_APPCONTAINER)

Tags: windows, file-io, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

CreateFile2 api is returning ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_IN_APPCONTAINER when the file is not present/available in the path. My code is as below

```
   CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS ms_param = {0};
   ms_param.dwSize = sizeof(CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS);
   ms_param.dwFileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY;
   ms_param.dwFileFlags = FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING;
   ms_param.dwSecurityQosFlags = SECURITY_DELEGATION;
   ms_param.lpSecurityAttributes = NULL;
   ms_param.hTemplateFile = NULL;

   g_hfile = CreateFile2(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, OPEN_EXISTING, &ms_param);
   if (g_hfile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
           return GetLastError();
   }
```

I have already looked into this thread:[CreateFile2 error in WinRT project (ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_IN_APPCONTAINER)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618592/createfile2-error-in-winrt-project-error-not-supported-in-appcontainer) , reporting similar issue. The solution suggested there doesnt work for me.

From this msdn page:[CreateFile2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422.aspx) *If the specified file or device does not exist, the function fails and the last-error code is set to **ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND** (2)*.But I am getting **ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_IN_APPCONTAINER** error

Comment: You specified `OPEN_EXISTING` as the creation disposition. Why does it surprise you, that the call fails in case the file doesn't exist?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Hi @IInspectable & user34660, Thanks for the response. From this msdn page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx, if OPEN_EXISTING is specified & if the file is not found, the error is ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. My app handles ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error for this api, but app doesnt expect to see ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_IN_APPCONTAINER error. 
Kindly let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Are you sure that you should get an `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` error? Maybe your *filename* points to a path, that is not supported. Or some of your flags (or combinations) are invalid. Note also that you linked to [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) in your question, but you are calling [CreateFile2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422.aspx).

Comment: Hi @IInspectable, Thanks for the response. In a hurry, I seem to have posted the msdn page for [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) instead of [CreateFile2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422.aspx). But if you see the description for **CreateFile2** it also says the same thing _If the specified file or device does not exist, the function fails and the last-error code is set to ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (2)._

Comment: CreateFile2 is not a way to bypass the sandbox restrictions.  You only get access to the directories that the appxmanifest asks permissions for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Hans Passant's, comment helped me figure out the answer. Since I cannot upvote the comment I am adding it as an answer here:

**CreateFile2 is not a way to bypass the sandbox restrictions. You only get access to the directories that the appxmanifest asks permissions for.**

After checking his comment, I debugged my app deeper & was able to see that under certain scenarios, app was trying to read/write to files which were outside of accessible directories.