# Windows UWP CreateFIle2 cannot read file in ApplicationData.LocalFolder

Tags: visual-c++, file-io, uwp, windows-10-universal, c++-cx

I am trying to build UWP app in C#. My app has a native library written in C++. Whenever the app tries to read a file in **ApplicationData.LocalFolder**, CreateFile2 api is returning **ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_IN_APPCONTAINER**. The file exists in the path specified to this api.

This is the sequence of operation in my app.

1. Launch app. App creates file & writes some data
2. Later on based on user input app tries to read data in this file

Step 1 is working fine. App is able to create the file & write data in it. Only when app tries to access it later on, does it get this error.

I get the path to **ApplicationData.LocalFolder** using

> Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path

This is the actual path I see in the app:

> C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Packages\ac7a11e4-c1d6-4d37-b9eb-a4b0dc8f67b8_yyjvd81p022em\LocalState\temp.txt

My code is as below:

```
CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS ms_param = {0};
   ms_param.dwSize = sizeof(CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS);
   ms_param.dwFileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY;
   ms_param.dwFileFlags = FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING;
   ms_param.dwSecurityQosFlags = SECURITY_DELEGATION;
   ms_param.lpSecurityAttributes = NULL;
   ms_param.hTemplateFile = NULL;

   g_hfile = CreateFile2(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, OPEN_EXISTING, &ms_param);
   if (g_hfile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
           return GetLastError();
   }
```

I tried CreateFile2 with both **OPEN_EXISTING** & **OPEN_ALWAYS** option for ***dwCreationDisposition*** parameter, but I see the same error in either case.

I had similar issue with [CreateFile2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610931/windows-10-createfile2-error-error-not-supported-in-appcontainer) earlier. But that was an problem with my app & I have fixed that issue. This time though the file is available within the LocalFolder, still I get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is related to the `dwSecurityQosFlags` you've set in `CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS`.

> When called from a Windows Store app, **CreateFile2** is simplified. You can open only files or directories inside the **[ApplicationData.LocalFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx)** or **[Package.InstalledLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation.aspx)** directories. You can't open named pipes or mailslots or create encrypted files (**FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED**).

The ***dwSecurityQosFlags*** parameter specifies SQOS information. In Windows Stroe app, we can only set it to **`SECURITY_ANONYMOUS`**. Using other flag will raise **ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_IN_APPCONTAINER** exception. This indicates that it is not supported in UWP app.

Following is the code I used to test:

```
StorageFolder^ localFolder = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;
String^ path = localFolder->Path;
path += L"\\MyFile.txt";

CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS ms_param = { 0 };
ms_param.dwSize = sizeof(CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS);
ms_param.dwFileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY;
ms_param.dwFileFlags = FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING;
ms_param.dwSecurityQosFlags = SECURITY_ANONYMOUS;
ms_param.lpSecurityAttributes = NULL;
ms_param.hTemplateFile = NULL;

HANDLE g_hfile = CreateFile2(path->Data(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, OPEN_EXISTING, &ms_param);

DWORD error = GetLastError();
```

If I don't have "MyFile.txt" under LocalFolder, I will get `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` exception, otherwise it will be `ERROR_SUCCESS`.